# ios9 HTTP load failed kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL (-9802)

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, amazon-ec2

I have an issue that appeared recently.

In my code, I load some images from an HTTP server:

```
let urlPicture = "http://images.mydomain.com/" + self.currentUser.pic
imageView.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: urlPicture))
```

I do not use HTTPS for my images server because I guess it would have been too slow, but maybe I'm wrong on this point.
A nodejs server is running in an AWS EC2 instance, and listens on port 80 to manage images.

Due to ATS restrictions, I declare an exception in my Info.plist file for my images subdomain:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>images.mydomain.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.2</string>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSRequiresCertificateTransparency</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.2</string>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Recently I added a new subdomain on the **same** AWS instance: https://api.mydomain.com
Another nodejs server listens on 443 port and manages the API.

Since this change, everything is fine in my app when I call the API, but when I load images I am facing the following issue:

```
NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)
```

Any idea fo fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.

It was on server side, the HTTPS server running on the same AWS instance is configured with HSTS:

```
var ONE_YEAR = 31536000000;
app.use(helmet.hsts({
  maxAge: ONE_YEAR,
  includeSubdomains: true,
  force: true
}));
```

The variable `includeSubdomains` set to `true` forces my other domain `images.mydomain.com` to use HTTPS protocol while it is a HTTP server.

To solve it, just exclude others domains in HSTS configuration:

```
var ONE_YEAR = 31536000000;
app.use(helmet.hsts({
  maxAge: ONE_YEAR,
  includeSubdomains: false,
  force: true
}));
```

Answer (score -2):

Can you add this in plist.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

Comment: The application will be published in appstore, so I cannot disable all ATS. That's the reason why I just put an exception for my images subdomain.

Comment: I added your suggestion, the issue is the same. I think that iOS automatically change HTTP to HTTPS for my request. Any idea to avoid this behavior?

Comment: Another point, the issue does not appear with the Xcode simulator but only with a real device.